# UNITY - Shoot Projectile on the direction of where the gun is facing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I Have a gun that spawn a projectile that bounces of colliders (a Ricochet). It is supposed to be shooting to the direction of where the gun is facing but what I am getting is the projectile always shoots 45 degrees upwards to the right I know this is because of my constant declared vector 2.

I tried using Vector2.up but it prevents the projectile to do the ricochet effect because it always wants to go upwards.

How should I implement those things? I just want the projectile to shoot to the direction where my gun is facing and bounces of on colliders. This is a 2D game btw. I have my codes attached below so you can see. Thanks!

**Projectile Script:**

```
private Rigidbody2D rb;
public static bool canMove = true;

void Start()
{
 rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
 rb.velocity = new Vector2(10f, 10f);
}
void Update()
{
 //transform.Translate(Vector2.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
 if (canMove)
 {
     rb.isKinematic = false;

 }
 else if (!canMove)
 {
     rb.isKinematic = true;
 }
}
```

**Gun Script:**

```
float offset = -90f;

public GameObject projectile;
public Transform shotPoint;
public GameObject child;

void Start()
{

}

void Update()
{
    Vector3 diff = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
    float rotZ = Mathf.Atan2(diff.y, diff.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotZ + offset);

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Instantiate(projectile, shotPoint.position, transform.rotation);
        Projectile.canMove = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Rigodbody.velocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-velocity.html) is in **World-Space** coordinates.

When you pass in

```
rb.velocity = new Vector2(10f, 10f);
```

it will go in world space 10 in X and 10 in Y direction.

---

In order to pass it in as local coordinates in general you can not always rely on `Tramsform.InverseTransformDirection` as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966333/7111561) since the `Transform` component. In this specific case it might work but in general you set velocities in `FixedUpdate` and in that moment the `Transform` component might not be updated yet!

---

But the `Rigidbody2D` component is so in general you can use [`Rigidbody2D.GetRelativeVector`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.GetRelativeVector.html) in order to convert a local vector relative to the Rigidbody into world coordinates:

```
// Might also be Vector.up depending on your setup
rb.velocity = rb.GetRelativeVector(Vector2.right * speed);
```

---

Note: it would be better you make

```
[SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rb;
```

and already reference it via the Inspector. Then you can get rid of the expensive `GetComponent` call.

Comment: Is the gun a `Rigidbody`? Because if it isn't, the only way to `Rigidbody2D.GetRelativeVector` is going to be relative to the projectile, not the gun. Which is intantiated with the `transform.rotation` of the gun, which brings us right back to "in that moment the (gun) Transform component might not be updated yet!" problem. Which is why I didn't go that route in the first place.

Comment: Also, `GetComponent` is expensive for performance-critical contexts like `Update`, but is generally fine for initialization. By having to set it in inspector, you introduce a point of potential failure (not setting, setting wrong, etc) for no good reason. That's premature optimization.

Comment: Since the GetComponent call happens for every bullet Instantiated it matters actually. And since the bullet is a prefab the amount of things you could possibly reference incorrectly here is very limited btw. And no, the Rigidbody is the projectile not the gun .. that's why I leave this code in the projectlie not in the place the gun is Instantiated .. since the projectile is Instantiated with the correct rotation it's own right/up vector points in the direction it wants to move. As said in this specific case `InverseTransformDirection` might be ok but in general you should go through the Rb

Comment: Depends on how many bullets and how often they get instantiated. As far as we know, the game may be anything between a "brick breaker" with very few bullets/balls on screen at a time, to a 2D top-down shooter with lots. I say we go with the least assumptions. --- Also, at the point where the amount and frequency of instantiation becomes relevant, the appropriate solution becomes different entirely. You avoid instantiation in the first place, with pooling. --- Lastly, no, the projectile is instantiated in the gun script, with gun transform rotation, which can be out-of-date as you argued.

Comment: @XenoRo to your first point ... yes that's exactly my point being: Setting it **once** in the Inspector is way cheaper then calling `GetComponent` even if it is only once for the instantiation but for each and every projectile ... and yes it is instantiated via the gun script ... but setting the initial velocity is done in `Start` of the projectile script which is instantiated with correct orientation. At start the rigidbody and transform are still in sync so both methods would work ... but as said I'ld prefer the one that works in general

Comment: Setting it once in the inspector is adding a point of failure. When the rigidbody is a dependency at sibling level, that's a point of failure for no reason. --- Yes, it's cheaper, performance-wise; but if you need that performance, it's the wrong solution in the first place, as you would avoid instantiations entirely with pooling, in which case `GetComponent` for the necessary instantiations is still ok. --- `Instantiate(projectile, shotPoint.position, /*gun*/ transform.rotation);` = Instantiating with current frame's, possibly out-of-date, orientation. Which leads to wrong velocity in bullet.

Comment: why should the `transform.rotation` be out of date? The gun seems to be no rigidbody but a normal GameObject ... The point of failure ... for me this is no real argument over performance .. I would always expect that someone will be able to reference the correct component in a prefab where there are no much alternatives .. GetComponent is more a fallback here .. anyway this was more a suggestion to the OP .. you don't have to take it ;)

Comment: You're the one who argued that it could. `in that moment the Transform component might not be updated yet!` --- If everything is perfect, this is still bad practice. Regardless of what you assume; with inspector, a mistake _**can**_ be made. With GetComponent, it _**cannot**_. But why do you assume it's just one prefab? And why do you assume there are not many alternatives? Both, another script changing the bullet prefab reference of the gun; and the bullet prefabs consisting of multiple objects, including multiple RBs, can still be at this point. **Many** instances may need correct inspector.

Comment: Moving to chat is failing for me. Can u try? --- This is clearly extended discussion at this point, lol.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are telling it to do so.

> rb.velocity = new Vector2(10f, 10f);

10 to the right, and 10 upwards.

---

Unless your projectile has a constant force applied to it, like a missile, get rid of everything related to forces or velocity in the projectile script. It will do you no good.

Then, on the **gun** script:

```
//...
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
    var projectileInstance = Instantiate(projectile, shotPoint.position, transform.rotation);
    var rigidbody = projectileInstance.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    rigidbody.velocity = transform.TransformDirection(yourDirectionVector);
    Projectile.canMove = true;
}
```

Where [`Transform.TransformDirection`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformDirection.html) is what makes `yourDirectionVector`, which is a direction relative to the gun, be transformed into one relative to world-space.